# Detect if Silverlight is installed from c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-oob

I am creating an `MSI` for installing my `Silverlight OOB` application. It should install Silverlight Plugin if it is not present, or the required version is not present.

So, how can I detect if Silverlight exists on my machine. If present how can I know which version is present.

My `MSI` is distributed, may not be downloaded from webpage, so I can't put any javascript and download the MSI package accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the registry. The following link shows the keys for 32 and 64 bit systems: [How To Determine Silverlight version on x64 machines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5317603/314334)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for the CLSID in the registry.  But I can't find anything official documenting what to expect in the registry.

This forum post has some details http://forums.silverlight.net/t/52103.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above, you could check the registry. Iss Silverlight is installed on the machine the following entry sould exist.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight
```

The attribute **version** contains the installed version.